# `yum history undo $everything` to bring CentOS back to original state?

Tags: centos, yum

I made a few yum transactions (8 to be exact),  and now my CentOS 7 is messed up. Is there a way to undo everything in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made a few yum transactions (8 to be exact), and now my CentOS 7 is messed up. Is there a way to undo everything in one command?

You can use `yum history undo` to undo those commands serially, in the reverse order they were "done".

It's not clear what you mean by "messed up". Note that `yum history undo` does not roll back at the filesystem level. It is not like a "windows restore point". `yum history undo` just tries to, erm, do the opposite of what it did initially, in the *hope* that this will result in returning the system to a prior state of workingness. If your system is actually "messed up", it is unlikely to do much good. You should just start over with a fresh install.